# Android studio: Background image not working - Cannot resolve symbol

Tags: android

I have an image and a button and I want to make a background another image.
The problem is that when I add **android:background="@drawable/celekula.jpg"** it doesn't work. I get this error:

Cannot resolve symbol '@drawable/celekula.jpg' less...
Validates resource references inside Android XML files

And these are the error details:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Color value '@drawable/celekula.jpg' must start with #
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.ResourceHelper.getColor(ResourceHelper.java:87)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.ResourceHelper.getDrawable(ResourceHelper.java:356)
at android.content.res.BridgeTypedArray.getDrawable(BridgeTypedArray.java:695)
at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:4175)
at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:578)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:211)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:207)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:203)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor152.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.onCreateView(BridgeInflater.java:163)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:717)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:785)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:222)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:858)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:834)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:861)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:834)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:324)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:429)
at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:389)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:548)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:533)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:966)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:533)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$53(RenderTask.java:659)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I have that image (celekula.jpg) in the all drawable folders. This is my xml code:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/celekula.jpg"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/tvrdjava"
            android:id="@+id/imageView8"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:cropToPadding="false" />

        <Button
            android:text="ButtonBlaTest"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It probably does not recognize the extension .jpg of your image,normally in the imageview, the indexed names are placed through drawable without the file extension. try to put the name without the extension and android studio should index it without problems. You can always try to make a "Clean" or "Rebuild" project to index your new images.

Comment: You're right ! I never thought about removing the extension *facepalm* Thank you Carlo !

Comment: Remember, this working for all type images, png, jpg, bmp, etc!